# NGINX: node.js + php on domain + subdomain

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, subdomain, config

I'm trying to set node.js app on main domain and php-based forum on subdomain. Node.JS app works on 8000 port. Here's my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name myawesomeapp.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        access_log off; 
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
        root /srv/myawesomeapp/static;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name forum.myawesomeapp.ru

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Both node.js app & php forum can't be reached at myawesomeapp.ru. 127.0.0.1:8000 shows nodejs-app. What's wrong with my config? Thanks.

p.s. my php files are placed in `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include any messages you see on response of trying to visit both vhosts. As well make sure you include this setup in your nginx config as well as `service nginx reload` after changing configurations.

In order to proxy nginx to node you have to use upstreams. Here is configuration that might suit your needs:

```
upstream node {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name myawesomeapp.ru;

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    access_log off;
    root /srv/myawesomeapp/static
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    expires 365d;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://node/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

For your forum try this config:

```
server {
  server_name www.forum.myawesomeapp.ru;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://forum.myawesomeapp.ru$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name forum.myawesomeapp.ru;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.php;
  charset utf-8;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    expires 365d;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, however forum.myapp.com still shows node app. I've tried both `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` and `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` options (with `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` listen option editing)

Comment: `service nginx reload` shows no errors, `sudo service php5-fpm restart` also does.

Comment: Make sure you have included the config properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try just remove this lines from your config:

```
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
```